# Can props be accessed in beforecreated of vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-props

In the vue docs, the part of "beforeCreate", I read the following:

> Called immediately when the instance is initialized, after props resolution, before processing other options such as data() or computed.

Does this means that I can get **props** in beforeCreate hooks? if so, how can I get it?
In my child component, I try like this to get the `message` passed by parent component, but failed.

```
export default {
  name: 'Child',
  props: ['message'],
  beforeCreate() {
    console.log(this.message)
  }
}
```

Comment: In Vue 3 it would be better to use `setup()` instead of `beforeCreate` and there you would have access to props.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the following snippet, looks like your code is fine:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      msg: 'aaa',
    };
  },
})
app.component('Child', {
  template: `<div>{{ message }}</div>`,
  props: ['message'],
  beforeCreate() {
    console.log('before create: ', this.message)
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.29/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <child :message="msg"></child>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. very useful answer.  I mistakenly think the beforeCreate is same between vue2 and vue3. My code is runing with vue2, and when I turn to vue3, it works well.